# sass: calculating percentage with pixels

Tags: css, sass

In one case, I need to combine a percentage variable with pixels in calculation.

Note It's not about keeping mixed units in generated css, so calc wouldn't work.

```
$fooPercent: 40%;

.abc {
  width: 100% - $fooPercent; // This works
}
.bar {
  width: 100px * (100% - $fooPercent);  // Intend to get 60px
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dividing the percentage by 100% should give you a decimal which you can then multiply by the pixel value.

```
width: 100px * ((100% - $fooPercent) / 100%)
```